# display flex flex wrap width issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I have a parent element It has 5 children (it could be any amount cause it is dynamic, but this is the current case)

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
</div>
```

The parent element has the following css applied to it

```
.parent {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 24px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: column;
    display: flex;

}
```

The child has these styles

```
.child {
    width: 116px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The issue is that the parent only has the width of one child (116px) even though it has three columns each being 116px wide.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Shmili, just to clarify - what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to have a parent wrapper that contains children but it should only be a specific height (48px) so it wraps after the 2nd row.

Comment: So, you want the parent wrapper to contain how many children before wrapping to to the second row?

Answer (score 0):

Put the flex-wrap: wrap below the flex-flow:column, this will solve the issue. Or just simply remove the flex-flow:column because it will conflict to the flex-wrap: wrap.

Please see below:

```css
.parent {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
    width: 116px;
    align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!-- flex-wrap below flex-column -->

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
    width: 116px;
    align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!-- no flex-column -->

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">Some text</div>
</div>
```